# CSS to hide INPUT BUTTON value text

Tags: css, internet-explorer, drupal, input, transparency

I am currently styling an `<input type='button'/>` element with the following CSS:

```
background: transparent url(someimage);
color: transparent;
```

I want the button to show as an image, but I don't want the `value` text to display on top of it. This works fine for Firefox as expected. However, on Internet Explorer 6 and Internet Explorer 7 I can still see the text.

I have tried all sorts of tricks to hide the text, but without success. Is there a solution to make Internet Explorer behave?

(I am constrained to use `type=button` because this is a Drupal form and its form API doesn't support image-type.)

Comment: I had the same issue and tried all of the 11 answers, and found out that these hacks (`text-indent`, and `padding-left`) only fix inputs that have a `type="submit"`, so i had to change from `type="image"`.
Anyway thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you including the `value` attribute at all?  From memory, you don't need to specify it (although HTML standards may say you do - not sure).  If you do need a `value` attribute, why not just state `value=""`?

If you do take this approach, your CSS will need additional properties for the height and width of the background image.

Comment: *head smack* -- Alright - this actually works for me .. and I'd already been setting width and height . so tnx !

Comment: It should be noted that this makes the button entirely useless for sight-impaired users.

Comment: That's actually a very valid point.  You could work around this by adding a title and alt attribute to the button, couldn't you?

Comment: This is very poor for accessibility.  You should consider marking a different answer correct.

Comment: It's also required in an MVC pattern to automatically bring the value of the button through into the controller. If there is a "submit" and "cancel" button on the same form then the value of the button can be used to determine which button was actually clicked.

Comment: I agree this isn't good for accessibility and it is worth noting that you should use this with caution BUT that was not part of the question. This answer solves the problem effectively. I am willing to bet that most websites being discussed here aren't even internationalized properly for other languages, let alone taking into account screen readers for the sight-impaired. ;)

Answer (score 55):

I use

```
button {text-indent:-9999px;}
* html button{font-size:0;display:block;line-height:0}  /* ie6 */
*+html button{font-size:0;display:block;line-height:0}  /* ie7 */
```

Answer (score 35):

I had the opposite problem (worked in Internet Explorer, but not in Firefox). For Internet Explorer, you need to add left padding, and for Firefox, you need to add transparent color. So here is our combined solution for a 16px x 16px icon button:

```
input.iconButton
{
    font-size: 1em;
    color: transparent; /* Fix for Firefox */
    border-style: none;
    border-width: 0;
    padding: 0 0 0 16px !important; /* Fix for Internet Explorer */
    text-align: left;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    line-height: 1 !important;
    background: transparent url(../images/button.gif) no-repeat scroll 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

well:

`font-size: 0;
line-height: 0;`

work awesome for me!

Comment: Nice one! This seems like the least disruptive workaround for IE.

Comment: haaaa duh how did i not think of this.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried setting the text-indent property to something like -999em? That's a good way to 'hide' text.

Or you can set the font-size to 0, which would work too.

http://www.productivedreams.com/ie-not-intepreting-text-indent-on-submit-buttons/

Comment: yes i tried this and the buttons disappeared .. font-size = 0 still shows a dot

Comment: text-indentation doesn't work in IE 7 and older - whole button gets indented, not only text

Comment: I had the problem with the dot in the middle of the button with `font-size: 0`, the trick is to add `line-height: 0` as well.

Answer (score 3):

The difference some of you are seeing in solutions that work or not in the different IEs may be due to having compatibility mode on or off.  In IE8, text-indent works just fine **unless** compatibility mode is turned on.  If compatibility mode is on, then font-size and line-height do the trick but can mess up Firefox's display.

So we can use a css hack to let firefox ignore our ie rule.. like so...

```
text-indent:-9999px;
*font-size: 0px; line-height: 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying `font-size: 0.1px;` to the button works for me in Firefox, Internet Explorer 6, Internet Explorer 7, and Safari. None of the other solutions I've found worked across all of the browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional statements at the top of the HTML document:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

Then in the CSS add

```
.ie7 button { font-size:0;display:block;line-height:0 }
```

Taken from HTML5 Boilerplate - more specifically [paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/](http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/)

Answer (score 2):

I had this noted from somewhere:

adding text-transform to input to remove it

```
input.button {
    text-indent:-9999px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```

Comment: What's the capitalize for? I won't try now but the rest seems a good idea.

Comment: @Bomboca for some reason it doesn't work without the capitalize on our beloved IE7

Comment: @grim, loool why didn't I think of that? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Write to your CSS file:

```
#your_button_id 
    {
        color: transparent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This works in Firefox 3, Internet Explorer 8, Internet Explorer 8 compatibility mode, Opera, and Safari.

*Note: table cell containing this has `padding:0` and `text-align:center`.

```
background: none;
background-image: url(../images/image.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
overflow:hidden;
border: NONE;
width: 41px; /*width of image*/
height: 19px; /*height of image*/
font-size: 0;
padding: 0 0 0 41px;
cursor:pointer;
```

Answer (score 1):

`overflow:hidden` and `padding-left` are working fine for me.

For Firefox:

```
width:12px;
height:20px;
background-image:url(images/arrow.gif);
color:transparent;
overflow:hidden;
border:0;
```

For the IEs:

```
padding-left:1000px;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
color:transparent;  /* For FF */
*padding-left:1000px ;  /* FOR IE6,IE7 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem. And as many other posts reported: the padding trick only works for IE.

`font-size:0px` still shows some small dots.

The only thing that worked for me is doing the opposite

```
font-size:999px
```

... but I only had buttons of 25x25 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, just do a `hook_form_alter` and make the button an image button and you are done!

Answer (score 0):

This following has worked best for me:

**HTML**:

```
<input type="submit"/>
```

**CSS**:

```
input[type=submit] {
    background: url(http://yourURLhere) no-repeat;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    font-size:0;
    height: 38px;
    width: 171px;
}
```

If you don't set `value` on your `<input type="submit"/>` it will place the default text "Submit" inside your button. SO, just set the `font-size: 0;` on your submit and then make sure you set a `height` and `width` for your input type so that your image will display. DON'T forget media queries for your submit if you need them, for example:

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width:600px) {
  input[type=submit] {
    width:200px;
    height: 44px;
  }
}
```

**This means when the screen is at exactly 600px wide or greater the button will change it's dimensions**

Answer (score -1):

`color:transparent;` and then any `text-transform` property does the trick too.

For example:

```
color: transparent;
text-transform: uppercase;
```