# How to limit text in input type button?

Tags: html, css

How can i limit text of button? Just to trim some long text inside button.
All I'm allowed to do is only change the CSS

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input style="?" type="button" value="Trim long long long long long long long text that goes beyond a specified length" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [It may answer your question, enter here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600438/css-to-hide-input-button-value-text)

Comment: Specify _"a specific length"_. Do you want the input to be 100px wide or do you want the input to show _n_ characters?

Comment: If you already know that there is too much text in that value, why not shorten it?

Comment: @YarinLevi What does that have to do with anything

Comment: If  you can't change the HTML element yourself what are you allowed to change? Adding to a stylesheet or adding some Javascript or...

Comment: why would you display a long text inside of a button use `<Button>` instead and then truncate text within it using `substr()`

Comment: I apologize for not specifying - all I'm allowed to do is only change the CSS

Comment: Feel free to add all clarification to your question by editing it. This should also contain how the result should look like, and what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: @FabianS. yes, for example 100px, how to specify it in the style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the input match a specific length in pixels (e.g. 100px) you need to set the `width`.
This will make your input take 100px width.

To get a proper text overflow you add `overflow:hidden` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`.

Lastly add your text into the `title` attribute too, so you get the full text as tooltip when hovering the button - This is optional but i'd strongly recommend it for accessibility reasons.

```css
.trimmedbutton {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input class="trimmedbutton" type="button" value="Trim long long long long long long long text that goes beyond a specified length" title="Trim long long long long long long long text that goes beyond a specified length" />
</body>

</html>
```